# How does a MATLAB generated binary knows its fullpath?

Tags: matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler, pwd, mcc

I have a MATLAB compiler generated binary (exe/jar/dll).

I would like to be able to get the full path of the binary itself at runtime.

Any ideas? Help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a tricky topic in deployed MATLAB. Internet searching will find complicated answers in MATLAB Central.

However, this might help.

```
[p,f,i] = uigetfile('')
```

It is a bit of a hack, but will find the directory containing the .exe, which is returned in p.

When I went back to get a link to the answer in MATLAB Central, I found [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92949-how-can-i-find-the-directory-containing-my-compiled-application) which also answers your question:

```
function currentDir = getcurrentdir
  if isdeployed % Stand-alone mode.
    [status, result] = system('path');
    currentDir = char(regexpi(result, 'Path=(.*?);', 'tokens', 'once'));
  else % MATLAB mode.
    currentDir = pwd;
  end
```